# Ubuntu 16.04 Error when trying to update: How to fix the package that is causing problems?

Tags: update-manager

The software updater doesn't work anymore. Each time I try to install updates it returns: `Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error.`

Looking at the details, it seems there is one package causing problems:

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJvjy.png)

It says:

```
aptd crashed with AttributeError in rebuild_mod_path():'_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

I also get an error notification every time I log into my computer. I assume it is related, but I'm not sure.
Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I would suggest opening a terminal and `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` and providing details from there.  Usually errors occur as a result of adding non-Ubuntu sources or software intended for another release, and the messages help us to work out the package causing you issues, so we can query `apt-cache policy` where it comes from etc.  If you provide additional info, please add it to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried to run those (I found them reading similar questions). I don't get errors, but the problem is still there, nothing changed.
When I type `sudo apt dist-upgrade`, among other things it returns:

`The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-42 linux-headers-4.15.0-42-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-42-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-42-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Is it useful?

Comment: Useful no - but if you want to remove those packages you can run the `sudo apt autoremove` as suggested in the message itself.

Comment: would you suggest to remove them? Is it safe?

Comment: They are old kernels, most of us use the latest kernel (with the latest updates) the older kernels only in case we have problems (and thus need to use the advanced options in grub to temporarily boot an older kernel so we can fix something). The system i believe tries to keep latest + 2 older kernels & reports when there are beyond that which is what you're seeing here (ie. 4.15.0.45 is current, .44 & .43 being two older backups, .42 now superfluous to needs).  You can confirm this with `ls /boot/vmlin* -ltrh`.  If you need disk space (in /boot/ partition) then yeah,  if not don't worry.

Comment: `uname -r` will print what kernel you're running; if that is 4.15.0-42 then it's a definite NO.